# How to remove duplicates from result returned by Bootstrap-3-Typeahead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, autocomplete

I have integrated Bootstrap3-typeahed in my project and everything works fine. Problem is i have duplicate entries in mysql database which properties i need to read but don't want them to be shown multiple times in autocomplete/suggest drop down.

For example, user types 'bab' in input field results that are shown:
**bab**ble
**bab**ble
**bab**bler.

Result that i'm trying to achieve is: **bab**ble **bab**bler

Here is the code that responds for showing results:

```
               $.ajax({
                    url:"engine/searchhandler.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data: {query:query, lang:$('#lang-pseudo').val()},
                    dataType:"json",
                    async: false,
                    success:function(data){
                        result($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return item;
                        }))
                    }
                })
```

I tried to sanitize result in this way but it doesn't seem to work (log shows empty elements):

```
                    success:function(data){
                        result($.map(data, function(item) {
                            var list = new Array();                                     
                            var unique = list.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
                              return index == self.indexOf(elem);
                            })
                            console.log(unique);
                           //return item;
                        }))
                    }
```

Can someone help me to remove duplicates from result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

If `data` contains your array:

```js
const withoutDupes = [...new Set(data)];
```

`Set`s can only contain unique values. The `[...]` converts the `Set` back to an array.

Without `Set`:

```js
// 'data', not 'list'
const withoutDupes = data.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
  return index === self.indexOf(elem);
});
```

Comment: type of withoutDupes will be an array?

Comment: Yes. Both `[...new Set(data)]` and `Array.prototype.filter` return an array.

Comment: this a great answer, thank you, but after i get withoutDupes i don't know how to return each element of it

Comment: You should be able to call your `result` callback with `withoutDupes`: `result(withoutDupes)`.

Comment: Yes, never mind i figured it out, got confused in my own code, need a break i guess =), thanks again for your answer